# Is the vowel 'r' not pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

Consonant *R* is definitely pronounced in the uvular. But is vowel *r* pronounced, too? British English doesn't pronounce their vowel *r* and I suppose German does that.

For example: *Morgen, sterben, Herr*

My book says *Morgen* is pronounced /morgn/. Isn't it more like /moagn/, /shteabn/ and /hea/?

And if so, is it safe to assume that German is different to French *r*, which is pronounced regardless of whether it's a vowel or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The R is always considered a consonsant in German but can have a vocalic sound in some circumstances. The examples you mentioned, however, are not among them:

- Herr [hɛʁ]
- sterben [ˈʃtɛʁbn̩]
- Morgen [ˈmɔʁɡŋ̍], [ˈmɔʁɡn̩]

A typical example for a vocalic sound is the ending *-er* as found in many German words:

- Lehrer [ˈleːʀɐ]
- Fahrer [ˈfaːʀɐ]
- Bruder [ˈbʀuːdɐ]

Other examples are when R is in the final position and follows a vowel:

- Tor [toːɐ̯]
- Uhr [uːɐ̯]
- Heer [heːɐ̯]

In the middle of a word, it's pronounced vocalic following a long vowel:

- Herd [heːɐ̯t]
- führte [ˈfyːɐ̯tə] (but führen [ˈfyːʀən])
- Pferd [pfeːɐ̯t], [feːɐ̯t]

And finally some prefixes like *er-*, *ver-*, *zer-*:

- erreichen  [ɛɐ̯ˈʀaɪ̯çn̩]
- vergessen  [fɛɐ̯ˈɡɛsn̩]
- zerreißen [ʦɛɐ̯ˈʀaɪ̯sn̩]

---

Note that this answer adresses common pronunciation and in some dialects the pronunciation may vary. IPAs are taken from the respective Wiktionary entries.

Comment: When I read her examples, I was reminded of some western German dialects.. "Hea Schneideah, höast Du? Was kostean die Kondoohhmä?"

Comment: Just like @hiergiltdiestfu pointed out, the ending "-er" can be sometimes pronounced more like an "-a", but that is either a dialect or simply people mumbling to much, it is not a rule.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for you all. I want to ask a few more questions, it that's not a bother to you.... By those rules, does 'Herr' in Herr Fretzen sounds like hea? But when I listen to the audio files for study, Morgen sounds like morgen. I believe this is because uvular trill is so irregular and unpredictable that it sounds like the trill is 'dropped' on the way pronouncing it. But no matter how hard it is to pronounce the trill right( for example, when  preceded by 'i' vowel, as in 'kaiserin'), it's still an uvular trill and proper, isn't it?

Comment: Almost when 'r' sounds like 'h', so to speak.. Even if it is pronounced(to my ear) like 'h', the place of articulation stays in uvular, and not in glottal, is this right?

Comment: I would add that it depends on the region. In the North of Germany, we tend to not pronounce the r in most of those cases (Herr, sterben, morgen ...). Even with professional speakers [(Susanne Daubner, Tagesschau vom 27.7.2017)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxi472bhzMA) I can't hear a pattern: *Herrn* (0:18) and *morgen* (14:28) do not have an audible r, *dort* (0:31) has one, and with *ordnete* (0:38) it's not quite clear.

Comment: I disagree within the first three examples (the three words from the question). For *Herr, sterben* and *Morgen* also this versions exist: [hɛɐ̯], [ˈʃtɛʁbn̩] and [ˈmɔɐ̯ɡŋ̍]

Comment: Listen to Vortarulo in https://de.forvo.com/word/herr/#de or to both speakers in https://de.forvo.com/word/nicht_schlecht%2C_herr_specht%21/#de Also to both speakers in https://de.forvo.com/word/sterben/#de and to Hans in https://de.forvo.com/word/morgen/#de

Comment: You should note that this answer talks about how pronunciation guides tell you to pronounce German, not about how Germans actually pronounce words - while there are speakers (and I'm among them) that actually say something like [ˈmɔʁɡn̩], those that say something like [ˈmɔɐ̯ɡn̩] are much more common at least where I come from, which is in the south.

Comment: ... and again it depends what part of the South. You seem to be from the South-East, whereas in the South-West it would be more like [ˈmɔʁɡŋ̍] or even [ˈmɔʁɡɐ] (the latter only in dialect).